# FlatFileItemWriter producing blank file

Tags: spring-batch

I am using FlatFileItemWriter in the following way in order to produce a file containing a list of item in [id, FirstName] format-

```
<bean id="FileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="processedtext.txt"/>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="-"/>
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="id,firstName"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the Job ends with-
    17:19:23,720  INFO main SimpleJobLauncher:111 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=FileToFileJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

The issue here is when I open the file processedtext.txt, it is blank.

Can you please let me know if something is going wrong and how to resolve the issue.

Comment: please add the complete xml job definition

Comment: Issue is resolved. I guess, it was because the output text file was not getting refreshed with the proper contents. I restarted my Eclipse and now the output file is showing data as per the expectations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of FaltFileItemWriter which needs to be used as follows

```
<property name="shouldDeleteIfEmpty" value="true"/>
```